# How to create warped / distorted line effect in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to know how to create the warped lines like the one in this photo. I am aware of the evelope tool but do not know how to use it or if it could be even be used to create this effect. 
[image: -]

Answer (score 2):

It's actually a bit easier than it may appear...

Although I've used just a flat series of paths here, you can use this same method with just about any artwork, except *linked* raster images (you must embed rasters for this to work). So if there's some size variation or color variation you'd like in the lines, add it.

[image]

All of it in action...

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that raster images do not get warped under the mesh? I wrote the opposite, but I use an ancient Illustrator that does it.

Comment: @user287001 I wasn't detailed enough :) Thanks for pointing that out. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

- Draw a bunch of lines, maybe blend two with a selected number of steps
- if you blended, then expand the blend, Ungroup
- Select the bunch
- go Object > Path > Outline the stroke ; that makes also line widths fluid
- go Object > Envelope Distort > make with Mesh; choose dense enough mesh
- select a node or several of them by the Direct Selection Tool. Move as you will
- add the rest (text A without a stroke, circle as a clipping mask)

NOTE:

- the zebra can contain also other patterns than lines. Everything will liquify that is selected to be under the mesh, even a photo (=raster image)
- before you start, experiment a little how dense your zebra should be and what is the proper general orientation. If it's too sparse, the overlaid shapes (A in your example) will have too low resolution. The orientation angle affects the visibility of the overlays. See an example:

[image]